# Trouble with NavController inside OnBackPressedCallback

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-navigation-editor

I am getting a `does not have a NavController set` error inside a OnBackPressedCallback. Here is the code

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.patient_info_fragment, container, false)

    if(Utils.connectedToInternet()){
        fragmentView.pastScreeningsButton.visibility = View.GONE
    }

    requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                Navigation.findNavController(fragmentView).navigate(R.id.action_patientInfoFragment_to_patientsList)
        }
    })
    setHasOptionsMenu(true)


    return fragmentView
}
```

I am only getting this error when I come back into the fragment where this is implemented.

I have `android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"` in the home fragment.

To clarify, I am using Navigation controller to do all my Navigation around my app and it works just fine. I only get this error inside this `OnBackPressedCallback` and only when the user navigates back into the fragment where this is implemented.

Let me know if you need to see any more of my code.

Comment: I am getting the fragmentView when I first inflate the fragment layout. I am updating the code with my full onCreate().

Comment: I wasn't aware I need to do a removeCallback. Where do I put it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might run into an issue with leaks of old instances of your fragment. Also it's not a good practice to store the created view within another variable like `fragmentView`. All in all your `onCreateView` implementation is doing too many things unrelated to its purpose.

I'd suggest to split up the functionality into relevant life-cycle methods and use the `fragment.view` directly within your callback. To not run into an issue with unattached views, you then bind and unbind the callback with the life-cycle.

```
class PatientInfoFragment: Fragment() {

    private val callback = object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_patientInfoFragment_to_patientsList)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.patient_info_fragment, container, false)

    override fun onViewCreated(
        view: View,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ) {
        if(Utils.connectedToInternet()){
            view.pastScreeningsButton.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(callback)
    }

    override fun onStop() {
        callback.remove()
        super.onStop()
    }
}
```

The callback life-cycle binding can be bound with the fragment as lifecycle owner calling the other `addCallback(LifecycleOwner, OnBackPressedCallback)`.

Additionally you could have a look into [Android KTX](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx) and [Kotlin Android Extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) to simplify your implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply. removeCallback is not a thing, pretty sure it happens automatically. The rest of your answer makes sense, ill make the changes in my code. Thanks again.

Comment: Where are you getting the view in your Navigation.findNavController(view) ?

Comment: The view comes from the fragment. Regarding the `removeCallback()` you're right, you'd have to call `callback.remove()` or use `addCallback(this, callback)` instead.

Comment: Sorry man, I am not getting it. How would I get the view from the fragment in global?

Comment: The `callback` is supposed to be the a property of your fragment. As it's also an inner class, it'll have access to [`view`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#getView()).

Answer (score 1):

Move your code in the `onViewCreated` and pass the `view` that is provided by the overriden method:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
                Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_patientInfoFragment_to_patientsList)
        }
    })
    }
```

If that also doesn't work, replace the `.navigate()` with `popBastack(R.id.framgment_where_you_want to go, false)`, in case your previous fragment stays on the `backStack`

Comment: have you included your fragment on the `nav_graph`

Comment: Yes, I have. The navigation works well when the fragment first loads, it is only when I navigate back to the fragment that I have this issue.

Comment: what xml element are you using? `<fragment/>` or `<FrameLayout\>`

Comment: using <fragment/>